# How to mock a class imported from the outside

Tags: pytest, pytest-django, pytest-mock

I want to write the testcase for the following function, but the mock for Schema is always wrong. Could someone help?

The file path: models/product.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    @cached_property
    def schema(self):
        # Avoid circular import
        from project.schema import Schema

        if self.name == "news":
            return Schema(
                Product.objects.get(name=self.name)
            ).schema
        return self._get_schema()
```

And here is the mock path:

```
with patch("models.product.Product.schema.Schema") as mock_schema
```